# Integrating $\int\frac{\sin^3x}{\cos x}\,\mathrm dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How would I integrate the following:

.$$\int\frac{\sin^3x}{\cos x}\,\mathrm dx.$$

I am not sure what to do. I could split $\sin^3x=(1-\cos^2x)(\sin x)$

Then get $\int \tan(x)(1-\cos^2x)$

But would this be the right way to go.

Comment: Try the Maple command [IntTutor](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) which gives hints and shows the required solution step by step.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $u = \cos x \implies du = -\sin x\,dx$

$$\begin{align} \int \dfrac{\sin^3x}{\cos x} \,dx & = -\int \dfrac{-\sin x\sin^2 x}{\cos x}\,dx \\ \\ & = -\int \dfrac{-\sin x(1 - \cos^2 x)}{\cos x}\,dx \\ \\ & = -\int \dfrac{(1 - u^2)}{u}\,du \\ \\ & = \int u \,du - \int\dfrac 1u \,du\\ \\ & = \frac{u^2}{2} - \ln |u| + C \\ \\ & = \frac 12 \cos^2 x - \ln |\cos x| + C\end{align}$$

Comment: I see so would I get $\int -\frac{1}{u}+u$ and then get  ln(u)+u^2/2

Comment: Almost: you get $-\ln u + \dfrac{u^2}2 + c$. Then replace $u = \cos x$, and you're done!

Comment: I see that make make sense. Ty

Comment: You're welcome! Just note the $-\ln u$.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you get $\int (\tan x-\sin x\cos x)dx$ which should be quite straight forward

$$\int\frac{\sin^3x}{\cos x}dx = \int\frac{\sin x(1-\cos^2x)}{\cos x}dx = \int (\tan x - \sin x\cos x) dx = \int (\tan x - \frac{1}{2}\sin 2x)dx$$

Comment: Actually, $\tan x - \sin x \cos x = \tan x - \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$.

Comment: Not quite: $\int (\tan x - \sin x \cos x)\, dx$

Comment: oh yeah, thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Do the change $y=\cos x$.